# Unclear usage of JMP FAR

Tags: assembly, x86, intel

In the Book *Rootkits: Subverting the Windows Kernel* Chapter 5: *Runtime Patching* Page 120-125 (Greg Hoglund, ‎James Butler, 2006)

he says that
`JMP FAR 0x08:0xAAAAAAAA` will jump to `0xAAAAAAAA`

but, Wiki says 
`0x08:0xAAAAAAAA = (0x08 * 0x10) + 0xAAAAAAAA`

what's true.

Comment: I have no idea what do you ask?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In protected mode, the selector values (the segment part of the address in your example) do not use the "shift by 4" calculation. Instead, the value is used as an index into the Local or Global descriptor table, and the base address from the table is used.

The linked code seems to be made for Windows. Windows uses a simple, flat memory model, where most selectors map the whole 4BG address space with the base of 0. That's why the selector 8 will map to 0 and the jump will (try to) go to the address 0xAAAAAAAA.

I'm not sure what's the point of using a far jump, I think a normal jump (without reloading the selector) would work just as well.